# Override opacity of a CALayer set in xib

Tags: ios

I'm trying to make a `UIView` on a `UITableViewCell` fade in when selected. In the xib file, I set the view's `opacity` to `YES`, and `alpha` to `0.4`.

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, (and I also tried putting this in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`) I have:

```
CABasicAnimation* fadeAnim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
fadeAnim.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
fadeAnim.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
fadeAnim.duration = 1.0;
[cell.shade.layer addAnimation:fadeAnim forKey:@"opacity"];
```

When the cell appears on screen, it turns black (opaque 1.0), fades to 0.0, and then jumps to 0.4. I only want the opacity of the cell to change when tapped.

In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, I have:

```
if (cell.shade.layer.opacity > 0.5) {
    [cell.shade.layer setOpacity:0.0];
} else {
    [cell.shade.layer setOpacity:1.0]; 
}
```

When I break on the first line of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, when I run `po cell.shade.layer.opacity`, LLVM tells me it's `0.4`. After I run `[cell.shade.layer setOpacity:1.0]`, it's still `0.4`. What's preventing the xib alpha property from being overridden?

I also tried:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[UIView setAnimationDelay:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

if (cell.shade.alpha > 0.5) {
    [cell.shade setAlpha:0.0];
} else {
    [cell.shade setAlpha:1.0];
}

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

but the result is the same.

I don't want to put the animation in `setSelected:` because the result of putting the code in either 'setSelected`or`didSelect`should be the same, and I want the new view to stay visible after it's selected, so conceptually it makes sense to put the code in`didSelect`.

Comment: I guess that didn't get totally what you want to achieve. why are you  using layers, instead of views properties that will act on the backed layer anyway?

Comment: why not try to use `cell.selectedBacgroundView` instead of new layer adding yourself?

Comment: The added view doesn't totally cover the cell's content.

Comment: @RosePerrone then still you can add a `cell.selectedBackgrondview` as you wanted frame size

Comment: Actually, if you use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method , then the animation won't look good actually. You should use `selectedBackgroundView` property or else `subclass` your cell and add a view in `setSelected:` and `setHighlighted:` methods

Answer (score 0):

If you need to need an animation only during selection and highlighting, remove the animation in `-cellForRowAtIndexPath` because this called when the tableview needs a cell, not displaying . Subclass as Dinesh said UITableViewCellClass and override `-setSelected:` `setHighlighted:`. 
Do not use layers unless you really have to (and it will happened in less of 20% of cases), UIView class has everything you need to do this kind of animation using simple animations block, layers introduce more concept about `modalLayer` and `presentationLayer` in animation. 
 Pay attention where you are adding views, `UITableViewCell` use a `-contentView` as container for your subviews.
If you want to know when UITableView is showing/selecting/dismissing a cell use the `UITableViewDelegateProtocol` it has a lot of methods that you should look. 
Just mentioning some of them :

```
– tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:
– tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:
– tableView:didEndDisplayingCell:forRowAtIndexPath:
```

Hope this helps.
Ciao,
Andrea

Comment: I addressed your comments at the bottom of my question.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is something easy that we are missing... what about setting -selectionStyle to none, now the overriden method should work properly